# C#: Check if a site and web feature is enabled?

Tags: 2013, development, master-page, event-receivers, sharepoint-on-prem

I have created a custom MasterPage and added a feature event receiver to deploy it to my farm to be able to enable it using PowerShell.

I have followed this excellent blog post on how to create the feature in Visual Studio and everything work's perfect.

[How to deploy a custom MasterPage in SharePoint 2013 using Visual Studio](http://frederik.se/how-to-deploy-a-custom-master-page-in-sharepoint-2013-using-visual-studio/)

However, when i tried to enable the feature in my test environment to a Site where publishing infrastructure already were published, i received this error several times on the application servers logs.

> Event log message was: 'Failed to create the 'Images' library.'.
>   Exception was: 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The feature failed
>   to activate because a list at 'PublishingImages' already exists in
>   this site.  Delete or rename the list and try activating the feature
>   again.     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.ProvisioningHelper.AddList(SPListCollection
>   lists, String urlName, String title, String description, Guid
>   featureId, Guid[] previousVersionFeatureIds, Int32 templateType,
>   Boolean& newListCreated)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.ProvisioningHelper.AddList(SPListCollection
>   lists, String urlName, String title, String description, Guid
>   featureId, Guid[] previousVersionFeatureIds, PublishingTemplateType
>   templateType, Boolean& newListCreated)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.AreaProvisioner.CreateImagesLibrary(SPList
>   approvalTaskList)'

It's kinda obvious that there were some problems as the publishing feature were already enabled and the "Images" (publishingimages) library were already in place. I would like to avoid this error when i'm ready to deploy the solution in our production environment.

From the blog post i mentioned earlier, this is a piece of the code for the event receiver:

```
string webAppRelativePath = topLevelSite.ServerRelativeUrl;
if (!webAppRelativePath.EndsWith("/"))
{
    webAppRelativePath += "/";
}

// Activate publishing infrastructure
site.Features.Add(new Guid("f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa"), true);

// Enumerate through each site and apply branding.
foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
{
    // Activate the publishing feature for all webs.
    web.Features.Add(new Guid("94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb"), true);
    web.MasterUrl = webAppRelativePath + "_catalogs/masterpage/MyCustom.master";
    web.CustomMasterUrl = webAppRelativePath + "_catalogs/masterpage/MyCustom.master";

    web.Update();
}
```

It's missing to check if the Publishing Infrastructure feature already are enabled. My server-side coding skills are kind of rusty, but i'm thinking to check if the site feature is added and then check for each web if the feature is enabled.

Am i on the right track code-wise?

```
Guid siteguid= new Guid("f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa");
Guid webguid = new Guid("94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb");

// Check if the Publishing infrastructure feature is enabled
if ((site.Features[siteguid] == null)) {
    // Activate publishing infrastructure
    site.Features.Add(new Guid("f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa"), true);
}
    // Enumerate through each site and apply branding.
    foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
    {
        // Check if the Publishing feature is enabled
        if (web.Features[webguid] == null){
        // Activate the publishing feature for all webs.
            web.Features.Add(new Guid("94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb"), true);
        }

        web.MasterUrl = webAppRelativePath + "_catalogs/masterpage/MyCustom.master";
        web.CustomMasterUrl = webAppRelativePath + "_catalogs/masterpage/MyCustom.master";

        web.Update();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is correct, `site.Features[siteguid]` this will return null if the feature is not already activated on the site.

So `if (site.Features[siteguid] == null)` will work as expected.

However the variable names should be fixed, `siteguid` doesn't seem to be Site GUID, it seems to be publishingFeatureGuid. Also `webguid` doesn't seem to be Web GUID, it seems to be masterPageFeatureGuid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've added some code to check if the web feature is activated as well (inside the foreach loop). Guess that would work fine then to?

Comment: Yes that will work fine too!